# Rails : doesn't execute db:migrate on Docker (Only on Apple m1 chip)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, docker, apple-m1

### environment

macOS Big Sur(version11.6).
Mac mini(m1, 2020).

Rails 6.0.3

**docker version**

```
Client:
 Cloud integration: 1.0.17
 Version:           20.10.8
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.16.6
 Git commit:        3967b7d
 Built:             Fri Jul 30 19:55:20 2021
 OS/Arch:           darwin/arm64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.8
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.16.6
  Git commit:       75249d8
  Built:            Fri Jul 30 19:53:48 2021
  OS/Arch:          linux/arm64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.4.9
  GitCommit:        e25210fe30a0a703442421b0f60afac609f950a3
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.1
  GitCommit:        v1.0.1-0-g4144b63
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  db:
    hostname: db
    restart: always
    image: mysql/mysql-server:8.0.20
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - ./mysql.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/custom.cnf
      - /var/lib/mysql
    mem_limit: 512M
    cpus: 0.5
    cap_add:
      - SYS_NICE # CAP_SYS_NICE

  elasticsearch:
    restart: always
    build: ./elasticsearch
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes=1
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - network.host=0.0.0.0
      - http.port=9200
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1g -Xmx1g"
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    mem_limit: 1536M
    mem_reservation: 1G
    oom_kill_disable: true
    cpus: 1
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'curl --silent --fail localhost:9200/_cluster/health || exit 1']
      interval: 2s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 50
      start_period: 30s

  web:
    restart: always
    build: .
    working_dir: /app
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "1k"
        max-file: "3"
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_started
      elasticsearch:
        condition: service_healthy
      redis:
        condition: service_started
    env_file:
      - variables.env
    cpus: 2
    mem_limit: 1G
    mem_reservation: 1G
    oom_kill_disable: true
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - "redis:/data"
    command: redis-server

volumes:
  mysql.cnf:
  redis:

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: (my network name*)
```

### Problem

all images run without problem by `docker-sync-stack start`, but when execute `bundle exec rake:migrate`, it does not show any information and does not create database (There is no error in console).

I could do it any problem on intel chip Mac, but on m1 Mac like that.

↓console

```
.
.
.
web-1            | + [ ! -d /app/tmp/pids ]
web-1            | + [ ! -d /app/log ]
web-1            | + [ -f /app/tmp/pids/server.pid ]
web-1            | + bundle check
web-1            | Warning: the running version of Bundler (2.1.4) is older than the version that created the lockfile (2.2.20). We suggest you to upgrade to the version that created the lockfile by running `gem install bundler:2.2.20`.
web-1            | The Gemfile's dependencies are satisfied
web-1            | + service cron start
[ ok tweb-1            | [....] Starting periodic command scheduler: cron.
web-1            | + echo Running migrations...
web-1            | Running migrations...
web-1            | + [ development = development ]
web-1            | + bundle exec rake db:migrate

(then after that nothing)
```

(I can connect to mysql server, but database has not created)
if you need more info, i will add them.

#### (add1)

docker-entrypoint.sh(this file also runs)

```
#!/bin/sh
set -ex

if [ ! -d /app/tmp/pids ]; then
  # Control will enter here if $DIRECTORY does not exist.
  mkdir -p /app/tmp/pids
fi

if [ ! -d /app/log ]; then
  mkdir -p /app/log
  touch /app/log/development-batch.log
  touch /app/log/development.log
fi

if [ -f /app/tmp/pids/server.pid ]; then
  rm /app/tmp/pids/server.pid
fi

bundle check || bundle install --jobs=4 --retry=3

# set puma restart
service cron start

echo "Running migrations..."
bundle exec rake db:migrate 2>/dev/null || bundle exec rake db:setup
bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml&
bundle exec rails s -b 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: "bundle exec rake:migrate, it does not show any information and does not create database" -> have you already run `rake db:create`?

Comment: I added file docker-entrypoint.sh (add1), this file runs. There is no "rake db:create", but on Intel chip, db was created without any problem

Comment: I suspect this is because your add1 script executes `db:setup`, which includes the create command.

Comment: yes, you are light. But database is not created hmm ...

Comment: I've tried again and sometimes in console shows "bundle exec rake db:setup", but still database is not created ...

Comment: The output that a command has been run does not mean it succeeded. Try breaking up `db:setup` into its subcommands and look for failures to isolate the issue.